# Show and hide JavaScript function for drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a drop-down menu for a site that i am working on, and I am having problems with hiding and showing the drop down with the code that I have been using.

Basically, I need this:

```
<a href="#"  onclick="showHide('collections'); return false;">The Collections</a>
```

to read in the browser like:

```
<a href="#" style="display:block">The Collections</a>
```

or display

```
<a href="#" style="display:none">The Collections</a>
```

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Menu Test</title>
    <!-- Begin css library -->
        <style type="text/css">
            html {
                overflow-y: scroll;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            body {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #444;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }

            /* Begin top bar 
                *************************/
            #top-bar {
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.99);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.99);
                box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.99);
                font-family: GillSansMTStd-Book;
            }
            #top-bar-content {
                position: relative;
                height: 94px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 1025px;
                text-align: "right";
            }

            #top-bar .wrap {
                padding-left: 33px;
                padding-right: 33px;
            }

            #top-bar .links {
                float: right;
                line-height: 94px;
            }

            #top-bar a {
                outline:0;  
            }

            #top-bar .links a {
            display: inline-block;
            color: #b9afa3;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: normal;
            letter-spacing: .8px;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-left: 30px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            #top-bar .links a:hover,
            #top-bar .links a.active {
            color: #746758;
            background: url(/HalstedDesigns/catalog/view/theme/margaretha/image/nav-rule.gif) top center no-repeat;
            }

            #top-bar .collections {
                display: none;
                background-color: #695d4f;
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 94px;
                width: 340px;
                text-align: center;
                margin-left: 80px;
                padding-top: 10px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.99);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.99);
                box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.99);
                z-index: 5;
            }

            #top-bar .collections a{
                color:#fff;
                display:block;
                line-height:26px;
                padding:10px 20px;
                margin:0;
                background-image:none;
                text-transform:capitalize;
                font-size:16px;
            }

            #top-bar .collections a.the-ardmore-collection {
                font-size:14px;
            }

            #top-bar .collections a:hover,
            #top-bar .collections a.active {
                background-color:#fff;
                color:#695d4f;
                background-image:none;
            }
        </style>
    <!-- End css library -->

    <!-- Begin jquery library -->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function showHide(shID) {
                if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
                    if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
                        document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'block';
                        document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    <!-- End jquery library -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="top-bar">
        <div id="top-bar-content">
            <div class="wrap">
                <a href="/" title="Home" float="left"><img src="image/halsted-logo.png"; alt="Halsted Logo"></a>
                <div class="links">
                <div class="collections">
                    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/" class="the-ardmore-collection font-gillsans ">THE ARDMORE COLLECTION</a>                
                    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/qalakabusha-sofa" class="lusitanaregular">Qalakabusha Sofa</a>      
                    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/qalakabusha-fabric-collection" class="lusitanaregular">Qalakabusha Fabric Collection</a>        
                    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/hand-bags" class="lusitanaregular">Hand bags</a>          
                    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/scatter-cushions" class="lusitanaregular">Scatter Cushions</a>         
                    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/batonka-stools" class="lusitanaregular">Batonka Stools</a>           
                    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/tablecloths" class="lusitanaregular">Tablecloths</a>         
                    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/place-mats" class="lusitanaregular">Place Mats</a>       
                    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/napkins" class="lusitanaregular">Napkins</a>         
                    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/table-runners" class="lusitanaregular">Table Runners</a>
                </div>              
                    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com">Art Into Design</a>        
                    <a href="#"  onclick="showHide('collections'); return false;">The Collections</a>
                    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
                    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/newsletter">Newsletter</a>        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally think it is better to use the :hover CSS property for menus. It is a lot easier to implement but you might have problems on mobile devices. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

However, if you really want it on the onclick event, you will need to add or bind your event. Here is the jQuery documentation for it: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

once you will have bind the event, you will have to use your function's "event" parameter to get which element you clicked on and then show the right menu.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem:**

1. You have no handle on the element you are trying to change inside your function. This is because you are using `getElementById()`, but the collections div has no id attribute defined.
2. You are referencing the element whose display you wish to toggle inconsistently. Sometimes you are using `document.getElementById(shID+"-show")`, and other times you are simply using `document.getElementById(shID)`.
3. There is a logic error in your if statement; the condition in `if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none')` should check whether the style IS set to none, if so we want to change the style to block, and vice versa.

**The Solution**

1. Add an id attribute to the collections div like so:

   ```
   <div id = "collections" class = "collections">
   ```
2. Inside your showID function replace all instances of `document.getElementById(shID+"-show")` with `document.getElementById(shID)`. In fact, an even cleaner way to do this would be to only call the function once and assign the result to a variable.
3. Change the condition in your second if statement to check if the display IS equal to none.

With all the changes mentioned, your final function will look something like this:

```
function showHide(shID) {
    var el = document.getElementById(shID);
    if (el) {
        if (el.style.display === 'none' || el.style.display =='') {
            el.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            el.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

You may notice I added an or in the if statement. This is because for some reason the initial value of `el.style.display` (before it is set using javascript in the function) is ''. Without this or condition it would take two clicks to display the menu the first time around.

Comment: Rather than add the OR blank. Reverse the logic. It will only be blank until it is written to.  
So the logic is, the first time will be a click to show the menu.  Therefore start with `if (el.style.display === 'block' ).`,  when it will not be `block`. Now it's covered for both blank and none.

Comment: @Misunderstood You sir, are a smart person.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple one line of code to execute to show hide.  Just a few lines to set up.

This code is tested and works well.  This is for just one menu but can easily to expand to multiple.
 **See my other Answer for multiple menus** (added after this one)

Setup code is run one time when the page loads.

### The setup:

Create an array to do the toggle.  This eliminates the if else.

```
var toggle = new Array;
toggle['none'] = 'block';
toggle['block'] = 'none';
```

Read the "collections div into a variable. Read once, never again.

```
var div = document.getElementById('d1');
```

The initialize the div so the DOM holds the display:none. Otherwise the first read will be null.

```
div.style.display='none';
```

### Then the showHide function

```
function showHide(id) {div.style.display=toggle[div.style.display];}
```

The div.style.display within the toggle array `toggle[div.style.display]` wil either be `block` or `none`.  Which ever, toggle will return the opposite. The sames as if it were `toggle['block']` which returns `'none'` which get assigned to the collections div.

### Note:

The JS code should be located just before the closing body tag `</body>`.  This way it will not be parsed until the HTML is all loaded.

Also it is very important to use a valid DOC Type.  If not the Browser has to guess and may guess wrong.  Slows own page load time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

### The JavaScript code:

```
</div><div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
function showHide(id) {div.style.display=toggle[div.style.display];}
var toggle = new Array;
toggle['none'] = 'block';
toggle['block'] = 'none';
var div = document.getElementById('d1');
div.style.display='none';
//]]>
</script></body></html>
```

Also way too much white space. This could significantly increase your transmission time. Most should be compressed as your pages should be gzipped.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><title>Menu Test</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<style type="text/css">
html {overflow-y: scroll;margin: 0;  : 0;font-family: sans-serif;}
body {background-color: #fff;color: #444;margin: 0px;  : 0px;}
/* Begin top bar *************************/
#top-bar {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.99);-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.99);box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.99);font-family: GillSansMTStd-Book;}
#top-bar-content {position: relative;height: 94px;margin: 0 auto;width: 1025px;text-align: "right";}
#top-bar .wrap {  -left: 33px;  -right: 33px;}
#top-bar .links {float: right;line-height: 94px;}
#top-bar a {outline:0;  }
#top-bar .links a {display: inline-block;color: #b9afa3;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;letter-spacing: .8px;text-decoration: none;margin-left: 30px;text-transform: uppercase;}
#top-bar .links a:hover,#top-bar .links a.active {color: #746758;background: url(/HalstedDesigns/catalog/view/theme/margaretha/image/nav-rule.gif) top center no-repeat;}
#top-bar .collections {display: none;background-color: #695d4f;color: #fff;position: absolute;top: 94px;width: 340px;text-align: center;margin-left: 80px;  -top: 10px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.99);-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.99);box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.99);z-index: 5;}
#top-bar .collections a{  color:#fff;  display:block;  line-height:26px;    :10px 20px;  margin:0;  background-image:none;  text-transform:capitalize;  font-size:16px;}
#top-bar .collections a.the-ardmore-collection {  font-size:14px;}
#top-bar .collections a:hover,#top-bar .collections a.active {  background-color:#fff;  color:#695d4f;  background-image:none;}
</style></head><body>
<div id="top-bar">
 <div id="top-bar-content"><div class="wrap">
  <a href="/" title="Home" float="left"><img src="image/halsted-logo.png"; alt="Halsted Logo"></a>
  <div class="links">
   <div id="d1"class="collections">
    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/" class="the-ardmore-collection font-gillsans ">THE ARDMORE COLLECTION</a>        
    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/qalakabusha-sofa" class="lusitanaregular">Qalakabusha Sofa</a>    
    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/qalakabusha-fabric-collection" class="lusitanaregular">Qalakabusha Fabric Collection</a>    
    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/hand-bags" class="lusitanaregular">Hand bags</a>      
    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/scatter-cushions" class="lusitanaregular">Scatter Cushions</a>     
    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/batonka-stools" class="lusitanaregular">Batonka Stools</a>       
    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/tablecloths" class="lusitanaregular">Tablecloths</a>     
    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/place-mats" class="lusitanaregular">Place Mats</a>     
    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/napkins" class="lusitanaregular">Napkins</a>     
    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/the-ardmore-collection/table-runners" class="lusitanaregular">Table Runners</a>
   </div>        
    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com">Art Into Design</a>    
    <a href="#"  onclick="showHide(1);">The Collections</a>
    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="http://halsteddesign.com/newsletter">Newsletter</a>    
  </div>
 </div>
</div><div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
function showHide(id) {div.style.display=toggle[div.style.display];}
var toggle = new Array;
toggle['none'] = 'block';
toggle['block'] = 'none';
var div = document.getElementById('d1');
div.style.display='none';
//]]>
</script></body></html>
```

**Note:**  The CDATA is to isolate the JS from HTML.  Without the CDATA the JS will sometimes cause HTML errors when running the W3C HTML Markup Validator.  It is a recommended best practice. 
The CDATA tells the Browser it is not HTML.  The format is

```
<![CDATA[  data goes here ]]>
```

The reason it has the two slashes is comment out the CDATA tags from the JS parser but still recognized by the HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

### The Multiple menu solution:

Multiple menus expands the showHide from one to **two lines of code.**

**Note:** The basics are documented in another Answer to this post that was posted prior to this one.

This time vs. the previous single method we save the divs to an array of variables. It is important this array is defined globally outside of any function.

This code is test and works well.

### The initialization code:

Create the arrays

```
var toggle = new Array;
toggle['none'] = 'block';
toggle['block'] = 'none';
var div = new Array;
```

The initialization in now in an init function.  Not required but is more reliable.  This way it will never execute before page load.

```
window.onload = init;
```

The init just get the showHide divs for the first time.

Then hides them all.

```
function init(){
  div[1] = document.getElementById('d1');
  div[2] = document.getElementById('d2');
  div[3] = document.getElementById('d3');
  div[4] = document.getElementById('d4');

  hideAll();
}
```

I have added a hide all function.  It is easier and quicker to hide all menus when another is displayed.  You do not want two menus open at the same time.  You could track the open menu and specifically close that one, but why bother?

```
function hideAll(){
div[1].style.display='none';
div[2].style.display='none';
div[3].style.display='none';
div[4].style.display='none';
}
```

### Wrapping it up:

I altered some of your HTML for test and demo purposes.

### HTML

```
    <a href="#" onclick="showHide(2)">Art Into Design</a>    
    <a href="#"  onclick="showHide(1)">The Collections</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showHide(3)">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showHide(4)">Newsletter</a> 
   <div id="d2"class="collections" >
    <a href="#" class="the-ardmore-collection font-gillsans ">THE ARDMORE COLLECTION</a>        
    <a href="" class="lusitanaregular">Qalakabusha Sofa</a>    
    <a href="" class="lusitanaregular">Qalakabusha Fabric Collection</a>    
   </div>
   <div id="d3"class="collections">
    <a href="">Hand bags</a>      
    <a href="">Scatter Cushions</a>     
    <a href="">Batonka Stools</a>       
   </div>
   <div id="d4"class="collections">
    <a href="">Tablecloths</a>     
    <a href="">Place Mats</a>     
    <a href="">Napkins</a>     
    <a href="">Table Runners</a>
    </div>
   </div>
    </div>
</div><div>
```

### JavaScript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showHide(id) {
  hideAll();
  div[id].style.display=toggle[div[id].style.display];
}
var toggle = new Array;
toggle['none'] = 'block';
toggle['block'] = 'none';
var div = new Array;
function hideAll(){
div[1].style.display='none';
div[2].style.display='none';
div[3].style.display='none';
div[4].style.display='none';
}
function init(){
div[1] = document.getElementById('d1');
div[2] = document.getElementById('d2');
div[3] = document.getElementById('d3');
div[4] = document.getElementById('d4');
hideAll();
}
window.onload = init;
</script></body></html>
```